# Why can I not replace text in .txt file

Tags: python, file, text, replace

Right now, I am making a simple game and am trying to record a high score and save it between times when the game is open. I have a file, `best_score.txt` that the high score is retrieved from on open and if `score == best` throughout the game, I want the current score to be saved in that file. The only text in `best_score.txt` is the score.

Currently, the file is opened and read from like this:

```
with open("best_score.txt", "r") as f:
    best = int(f.read())
    old_best = best
```

The high score(`best`) is pulled from the file, and I have a second copy of the high score(`old_best`) saved for later.

During the game, if someone beats their high score, `best` will be set equal to their score as it goes up.

Once they restart or close the game, if `score == best` this code runs:

```
with open("best_score.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(f.replace(str(old_best), str(best)))
```

This is intended to search for the original high score at the start of the game(`old_best`) and replace it with the new high score. Right now, when I run the game and beat the high score, the new one doesn't get recorded. The text file just becomes empty with no text in it at all, or it remains as the previous high score. What am I doing wrong, or what other method can I do to save the score in a text file?

I know there are [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390948/replace-string-python-txt-text) on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file) and explanations on how to [write text](https://pytutorial.com/python-script-replace-text-in-file) on [other websites](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/), but I just can't get mine to work. This is my first "big" project in programming(100+ lines) and this is the only thing that's really stumping me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overcomplicating it:

```
with open("best_score.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(best)
```

This will overwrite the text with the new text.

Comment: Thank you. I guess i was just missing how easy it could be. I didn't know .write would just replace text in the file.